# Symfony Routing with locale No route found for "GET /login_check/"

Tags: yaml, symfony

today I implemented a multilanguage-feature for my project and it works just great. But just the point I was trying to login again. Everytime I want to login this is the error:

> No route found for "GET /login_check/" (from "http://localhost:8000/de/")

I googled a lot but found little.

My routing.yml:

```
project:
    resource: "@AeTmProjectBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'

cms:
    resource: "@AeTmCMSBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'

donation:
    resource: "@AeTmDonationBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'

homepage:
    resource: "@AeTmHomepageBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'

mailer:
    resource: "@AeTmMailerBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'

user:
    resource: "@AeTmUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'

sponsor:
    resource: "@AeTmSponsorBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'

statistics:
    resource: "@AeTmStatisticsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'

fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'

BladeTesterCalendarBundle:
    resource: "@BladeTesterCalendarBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'
```

My security.yml firewall:

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                #provider: fos_userbundle
                #csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                success_handler: redirect.after.login
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                always_remember_me: true
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            switch_user:  { role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
```

And my config.yml framework:

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: de }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: false }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
```

Parameters.yml:

```
locale: de
    app.locales: "|de|en"
    locale_supported:
        en_EN: en
        de_DE: de
```

If anyone has an idea, I would be very thankfull!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have add a prefix to FosUserBundle routes in your routing.yml. Maybe this is the problem. Try to change the check path of your form login in your firewall.